# how to check uploaded image size is greater than 2MB in php?

Tags: php, html

I am working on image compression in php.

```html
<?php
if ($_POST) {
 echo $_FILES['file']['size'];
}
?>
<html>
    <head><title>Php code compress the image</title></head>
    <body>
  <form action="" name="myform" id="myform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <ul>
    <li>
     <label>Upload:</label>
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
    </li>
    <li>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="submit btn-success"/>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

This is working fine with the images less than 2MB.

if size>2MB then even its not showing in `$_FILES` after clicking on the submit button

Comment: to earase the max upload size take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size (i thought this is what you want) otherwise check the filesize in $_FILES ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check `$_FILES['file']['error']` and check if it's value is equal to the magic constant `UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE`

```
if ($_FILES['file']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE) { 
    //uploading failed due to size limmit
}
```

Comment: that'd just mean it failed with a "too big" error... !== perhaps?

Comment: Just realized what the comment said. My brain clearly is in holiday mode a bit too early. :/

Comment: indeed. it's gonna be a long day.

Answer (score 3):

You first problem is that you're not checking if an upload was successful. You cannot use ANYTHING in $_FILES until you've checked for that error. And checking for $_POST is not "error checking".

At bare minimum you should have

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   if ($_FILES['file']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        die("Upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['file']['error']);
   }
   ... got here, upload was successful
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the "upload_max_filesize" and/or "max_post_size" setting. Check for the setting in your php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if the uploaded size is greater than 2 mb it shows an error

```
if($file_size > 2048) {
    $errors[]='File size is greater than 2 MB';
}
```

Or if you want to upload image size more than 2 mb then edit your `php.ini` file and change "upload_max_filesize" and/or "max_post_size"  value.